# Como apresentar uma única vez a fatia de um gráfico sem repetir

Tags: c#, xamarin

Tenho uma tabela chamada **ItensLib**. Essa tabela eu guardo os itens de uma venda. Nessa tabela, fiz um somatório para Lucro e Total. O problema, é que, por exemplo, a venda com esse **ID:100030087** ela possui 5 itens e se faço o gráfico dessa venda, eu terei a fatia do lucro repetida 5 vezes(mesmo percentual). Aí vocês perguntam: Não existe uma tabela que tenha a venda em si, armazenada? Sim existe a tabela **Liberacao**, mas nessa tabela eu tenho apenas o total da venda. Por ela, segundo o cliente, não tenho como calcular o lucro dessa venda. Pensei em criar uma **DTO** que une as duas tabelas e trouxesse apenas o **Total** e o **LucroTotal**, mas ainda não fiz. Será que uma **DTO** nesse padrão resolveria? Eu teria o gráfico com uma pizza e uma fatia apenas?
Apenas para constar, abaixo o meu gráfico usando ***SfChart***

```
private async void CriaChart()
        {
            SfChart chart = new SfChart();
            DataService dataService = new DataService();

            try
            {
                PieSeries pieSeries = new PieSeries()
                {
                    ItemsSource = await dataService.GetItensLibAsync(IdOrcamento),
                    XBindingPath = "LucroTotal",
                    YBindingPath = "SomaTotal"
                };

                pieSeries.DataMarker = new ChartDataMarker();
                chart.Legend = new ChartLegend();
                chart.Title.Text = "Gráfico da Venda";
                pieSeries.DataMarker.LabelContent = LabelContent.Percentage;
                chart.Series.Add(pieSeries);

                this.Content = chart;

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                string err = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Comment: seguindo uma lógica simples...faça um DTO da venda, e dentro dele, a lista de itens... feito isso você na classe de venda você consegue realizar qualquer calculo que envolva os itens...

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, como assim. Deixa eu entender isso. Como seria isso? O DTO da venda só preciso do ID e do Total e como eu chamaria os itens?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, fiz um join na lambda e mesmo assim não funcionou. Não sei se foi isso que vc sugeriu.

Comment: sinceramente, não consegui entender qual o objetivo final, rs gráfico da venda, mostrando o percentual de lucro de cada item ?! é isso ?

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, o cliente me pediu o seguinte. Um gráfico que mostre o total da venda(somando todos os itens) e o lucro daquela venda. Isso entrou por último, por meu cliente. Acontece que o banco deles está bem fora dos padrões de um banco. Principalmente que ele tem uma tabela totalizadora onde consigo pegar o total da venda, mas não tenho como calcular o lucro e etc.